# Change textbox value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to update the value of text box from where I'm getting initial value to add product to cart.
Now I'm applying round function & I want to update the value of text box that is because I'm using ajax & if I'm applying round function, user must know how system calculated everything.

Here's my simple code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).delegate('.purchasenow','click', function(e){
    var buynow=this;
    var productid = $(this).attr('id');
    var quantity = $('.quo_'+productid).val();
    var quantity = Math.round(quantity);
    alert(quantity); //This gives the value
    $('.quo_'+productid).value = quantity; //This is not working
});
});
```

Can anyone tell why it's not working? It's very simple but I'm not able to find out the cause.

Comment: can you create jfiddle?

Comment: Because a jQuery object *doesn't have access to the DOM methods*. jQuery uses [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/), the **DOM** uses `.value`.

Comment: Yes agree to it, however `$('.quo_'+productid).val(quantity);` this works

Comment: Well yes; of course it does: that's because `.val(quantity)` is a jQuery method. Which *is available to* a jQuery object...

Comment: Yup, that was I missing, thanks a lot for info :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
$('.quo_'+productid).val(quantity);
```

The jQuery selector returns a wrapped object, not the actual DOM element.  I don't think wrapped object has the .value property

Comment: This works, I'd never tried this, I was using my method for all the value change. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

you are almost correct the only thing why it is not working because your syntax is wrong

this is the correct syntax for jQuery

```
$('.quo_'+productid).val(quantity);
```

if you want it in javascript

```
var txt = document.getElementById("quo_"+productid);
txt.value = quantity;
```