# Why does jQuery not assign a value to a Node's property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Given the following HTML:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Text input:</legend>
        <label>Label for the <code>input</code> element:
            <input type="text" id="textDemo" value="..." />
        </label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Radio Inputs</legend>
        <label>Male
            <input type="radio" name="gender" id="genderM" />
        </label>
        <label>Female
            <input type="radio" name="gender" id="genderF" />
        </label>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Why does this jQuery not correctly assign, or change, the node's property:

```
// using 'css()' shows the correct element was selected, but the
// value is not being set:
$('#textDemo').css('color','red').value = 'The new jQuery-changed value';

console.log($('#textDemo').value); // >> undefined
```

[JS Fiddle reproduction of this issue](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Nww32/).

Similarly, the following *also* does not work:

```
// finding the parent element, and setting its color to red
// verifies that we've started from the correct element
// ('end()' takes us back to the initial selector):
$('#genderF').parent().css('color','red').end().checked = true;

console.log($('#genderF').checked); // >> undefined
```

[JS Fiddle reproduction of this issue](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Nww32/2/).

Why can't jQuery correctly access/set the Node's properties (even when the relevant Nodes are correctly selected)?

Comment: This question is posted because *twice* today I've come across questions in which users are seemingly surprised that a DOM property (of a Node in the jQuery collection) isn't immediately accessible by simple chaining ([first](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24603292/), [second](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24614100/)). This may not be an ideal canonical, but I really just wanted somewhere to point people that (subsequently) get confused by this whole thing. This is, of course, a community wiki: any edits, revisions and improvements would be welcome (and much appreciated!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the following syntax:

```
$('#textDemo').css('color','red').value = 'The new jQuery-changed value';
```

Is that while the correct element was selected, the `$('#textDemo')` element is wrapped in a jQuery object, whereas `.value` is a property of that *wrapped* DOM Node itself, and the two cannot be chained together and are not interchangeable.

To achieve the intent of the above code, we can either use a jQuery method:

```
$('#textDemo').val('The new jQuery-changed value');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Nww32/3/).

Or:

```
// here we use 'prop()' to set the property of the elements contained
// within the jQuery object:
$('#textDemo').prop('value', 'The new jQuery-changed value');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Nww32/6/).

Or, we can select with jQuery and then 'retrieve' the DOM Node from the jQuery object:

```
// because a jQuery object (sort of) imitates an array, it's possible
// to retrieve a specific element from the collection(1), here we're
// retrieving the zeroeth element (which is the only element),
// effectively 'unwrapping'(2) it from the jQuery object. This 'unwrapped'
// element is the DOM node, and therefore has DOM properties (and methods):
$('#textDemo')[0].value = 'The new jQuery-to-DOM changed value';
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Nww32/4/).

Or:

```
// similar to the above approach, but here we use a jQuery method
// to retrieve the same, zeroeth, element; 'get()' returns the DOM node
// from the supplied index(1), and therefore has access to the properties
// of, well, itself:
$('#textDemo').get(0).value = 'The new jQuery-to-DOM changed value';
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Nww32/5/).

The same type of approaches can be used for the radio `<input>` elements also, except that `checked` is a property so, to use jQuery, the *only* option is to use `prop()` (as above, but with a different property-name and value):

```
// 'checked' is a Boolean attribute in HTML it's presence means that
// the relevant radio-input (also true of checkbox-inputs) will be checked
// (though it can become unchecked if another radio-input later in the
// same group is subsequently checked; and under XHTML it seems that the 'checked'
// attribute must have the value of 'checked' to be considered valid):
$('#genderF').prop('checked', true);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Nww32/7/).

And for XHTML that'd be:

```
$('#genderF').prop('checked', 'checked');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Nww32/8/).

That approach also works under HTML (but under HTML *any* `value`, including no value, could be equally valid (for example [`.prop('checked','fish fingers and custard')`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Nww32/9/)).

Of course, as above, we can *also* use `get()`:

```
$('#genderF').get(0).checked = true;
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Nww32/10/).

And index-notation:

```
$('#genderF')[0].checked = true;
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Nww32/11/).

Incidentally, for Boolean properties (`checked`, `selected`, `disabled` and quite a few others) it can be tempting to use the appropriately-named `removeProp()` to *remove* that property as a means of unsetting the `checked` property:

```
$('#genderF').prop('checked', true); // setting
$('#genderF').removeProp('checked'); // removing
$('#genderF').prop('checked', true); // this depends on the version of jQuery
```

In the 1.x branch of jQuery (up to and including version 1.11) this doesn't work *because we entirely removed the `checked` property*: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Nww32/11/).

In the 2.x branch, however, that seems to have been fixed and `removeProp()` no longer prevents the node from having the specific property(3): [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Nww32/12/).

Regardless of this apparent change (at least in Chrome 35/Windows 8.1) the documentation (see references, below) still explicitly states:

> **Note:** Do not use this method to remove native properties such as checked, disabled, or selected. This will remove the property completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element. Use .prop() to set these properties to false instead.

With that in mind, for a native, Boolean, property it's best to use `prop()`, again:

```
$('#genderF').prop('checked', true); // setting
$('#genderF').prop('checked', false); // removing
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Nww32/13/).

Incidentally, `prop()` was introduced in jQuery 1.6, prior to that `attr()` could be used in much the same way (since jQuery compensated for the differences between attributes and properties), for example:

```
$('#textDemo').attr('value', 'The new jQuery-changed value');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Nww32/17/).

And:

```
$('#genderF').attr('checked', true);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Nww32/16/).

(Note the use of jQuery 1.5.2, in those previous two demos).

Although the documentation does note:

The difference between attributes and properties can be important in specific situations. **Before jQuery 1.6**, the `.attr()` method sometimes took property values into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause inconsistent behavior. **As of jQuery 1.6**, the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while `.attr()` retrieves attributes.

In closing, it's worth making the point that the reverse is *also* true, DOM Nodes don't have access to any of the jQuery methods; even those DOM Nodes that were once in a jQuery object are 'only' DOM Nodes. Though I can't think of any common examples upon which this point could be illustrated.

References:

- jQuery:

  - [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
  - [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
  - [`removeProp()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeProp/).
  - [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

---

1. But yes, you *do* have to know, in advance (via some means outside the scope of this question), the index of the specific element you want to 'retrieve'
2. I'm aware that my...analogies(?) are relatively terrible. I can only apologise, I'm sorry.
3. I'm am so very, *very* glad I decided to check that, because I wasn't aware that it wasn't a thing any more under 2.x. I could've looked really stupid at that point.